# How do I assign two or more values to a single node in a singly linked list in python?

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list

I wanted to create a singly linked list with two values a node as practice after having successfully done it with one value per node, though I have no idea how exactly to approach this.

I've tried to convert the code for a generic linked list to one with two values a node, though it hasn't come close at all. I'd really appreciate any help with this.

**The problem itself:**

When I try to use the getTitle() method, it returns the error: "AttributeError: 'LinkedList' object has no attribute 'title'". The way I've tried to assign the values to a node was by simply having an extra value parameter, though looking at the error, it's probably resulted in nothing being assigned to the node.

These are my codes.

Generic singly linked list:

```
class Node:
def __init__(self, newData=None, nextNode=None, position=0):
    self.data = newData
    self.next = nextNode
    self.position = position

def getData(self):
    return self.data

def setData(self,newData):                 
    self.data = newData

def getNext(self):                         
    return self.next

def setNext(self,newNode):                
    self.next = newNode

def setFirst(self, newNode):
    self.head = newNode

class LinkedList:
def __init__(self):
    self.head = None
    self.tail = None
    self.size = 0

def getSize(self):
    return self.size

def printAll(self):
    if self.head == None:
        print("List is empty")
        return
    current = self.head
    while current != None:
        print(current.data)
        current = current.next

def searchForNode(self, data):               
    if self.head == None:
        print("List is empty")
        return
    current = self.head

    while current:
        if current.getData() == data:
            return True
        else:
            current = current.getNext()
    return False

def locateNode(self, data):             
    if self.head == None:
        print("List is empty")
        return
    current = self.head
    position = 0

    while current:
        if current.getData() == data:
            return position
        else:
            current = current.getNext()
            position+=1
    return False

def deleteNode(self, data):
    if self.head == None:
        print("List is empty")
        return
    current = self.head

    if current.getData() == data:
        self.head = current.getNext()
    else:
        while current.getNext() != None:
            if current.getNext().getData() == data:
                current.setNext(current.getNext().getNext())
                self.size-=1
                if current == self.tail:
                    current = current.next
                    self.tail = current
                return

            current = current.getNext()

def addNodeAtPosition(self, data, position):
    newNode = Node(data)
    if position == 0:
        newNode.setNext(self.head)
        self.head = newNode
        self.size+=1
    elif position > self.size:
        current = self.tail
        current.setNext(newNode)
        self.size+=1
        self.tail = current.getNext()
    else:
        nextPos = 1
        current = self.head
        while current.getNext():
            if nextPos == position:
                newNode.setNext(current.getNext())
                current.setNext(newNode)
            current = current.getNext()
            nextPos+=1
        self.size+=1

def deleteNodeAtPosition(self, position):
    if self.head == None:
        return
    current = self.head

    if position == 0:
        self.head = current.next
        current = None
        return

    for i in range(position -1 ):
        current = current.next
        if current is None:
            break

    if current is None:
        return

    if current.next is None:
        return

    next = current.next.next
    current.next = None
    current.next = next

def addNodeToFront(self, data):
    newNode = Node(data)
    newNode.next = self.head 
    self.head = newNode

def deleteNodeFromFront(self):
    current = self.head
    self.head = current.next

def addNodeToEnd(self, data):
    newNode = Node(data)
    if self.head == None:
        self.head = newNode
        self.tail = newNode
    else:
        self.tail.next = newNode
        self.tail = newNode

def deleteNodeFromEnd(self):
    previous = None
    current = self.head
    while current.getNext():
        previous = current
        current = current.getNext()
        self.tail = current
    if previous:
        previous.setNext(None)
```

Start of attempted new code (rest is untouched):

```
class Book:
def __init__(self, newTitle=None, newAuthor=None, nextNode=None, position=0):
    self.title = newTitle
    self.author = newAuthor
    self.next = nextNode
    self.position = position

def getTitle(self):
    return self.title

def setTitle(self, newTitle):                 #for setting a new title to a Book
    self.title = newTitle

def setAuthor(self, newAuthor):
    self.author = newAuthor

def setBook(self, newTitle, newAuthor):
    self.title = newTitle
    self.author = newAuthor

def getNext(self):                         #for getting the location of the next Book
    return self.next

def setNextTitle(self, newTitle):                 #for setting a new data to the next Book
    self.next = newTitle
```

Comment: 2 values in the same Node... so just put two variables in that Node class... I don't understand your question and issues you are facing. For example: `self.data1 = newData1` and `self.data2 = newData2`

Comment: Can you please specify what part of the code are you having difficulty with? What doesn't work?

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: @MooingRawr: Sorry, I forgot to mention the problem. The thing is, when I try to use the getTitle() method, it returns the error: "AttributeError: 'LinkedList' object has no attribute 'title'". The way I've tried to assign the values to a node was by simply having an extra value parameter, though looking at the error, it's probably resulted in nothing being assigned to the node.

Comment: Python doesn't really use getters and setters like other popular language. Just access the variable you need.... object.variable_name=

Comment: @MooingRawr: Thanks a lot! I managed to figure it out after this.